# DatetimePicker in asp.net 2005

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2005

Using C# and ASP.Net 2005

I want to add the Datetimepicker Control in my web page.  I cannot able to find the control in VS 2005

How to get the DateTimePicker Control in VS2005

Comment: It's called a Calendar. @Darin Dimitrov's answer links to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may take a look at [this one](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/Samples/Calendar/Calendar.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a Date AND Time picker, there aren't any that come with VS, or even jQueryUI.  I started using AnyTime+, and it works very well.  The UI is very friendly and code is simple.

http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use jQuery and jQueryUI to get a very powerful date picker:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

jQuery is packaged with ASP.NET as of the .NET 4 time frame and is officially supported by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

This bootstrap DateTimepicker is good I think https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker. It does not take too long to implement, especially if your site has used JQuery.